# Screenshot using SharpDX and EasyHook transparent

Tags: screenshot, directx-11, sharpdx, easyhook

I have been struggling in taking screenshots with DirectX, the problem is, it's working but seems to be missing some colors (black outline is missing for example), and some stuff that is also rendered by DX doesn't show.

I have uploaded the images (how the image should render and the rendered one) and also the code, what might be the issue?

[Correct Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTvs8.jpg)
[Rendered Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtOEj.jpg)

Greetings

```
public class Screenshot
    {
        public static void TakeScreenshot(string name = null)
        {
            var t = new Thread((ThreadStart) delegate
            {
                // destination folder
                var destinationFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments, Environment.SpecialFolderOption.Create) + "\\My Software\\Screenshots";
                if (!Directory.Exists(destinationFolder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolder);

                // file name
                string filename = name;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                    filename = "image-" + (Directory.GetFiles(destinationFolder, "*.png").Count() + 1).ToString("000") + ".png";

                // # of graphics card adapter
                const int numAdapter = 0;

                // # of output device (i.e. monitor)
                const int numOutput = 0;

                // Create DXGI Factory1
                var factory = new Factory1();
                var adapter = factory.GetAdapter1(numAdapter);

                // Create device from Adapter
                var device = new Device(adapter);

                // Get DXGI.Output
                var output = adapter.GetOutput(numOutput);
                var output1 = output.QueryInterface<Output1>();

                // Width/Height of desktop to capture
                int width = ((SharpDX.Rectangle)output.Description.DesktopBounds).Width;
                int height = ((SharpDX.Rectangle)output.Description.DesktopBounds).Height;

                // Create Staging texture CPU-accessible
                var textureDesc = new Texture2DDescription
                {
                    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
                    BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
                    Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
                    Width = width,
                    Height = height,
                    OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
                    MipLevels = 1,
                    ArraySize = 1,
                    SampleDescription = { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
                    Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging
                };
                var screenTexture = new Texture2D(device, textureDesc);

                // Duplicate the output
                var duplicatedOutput = output1.DuplicateOutput(device);

                bool captureDone = false;
                for (int i = 0; !captureDone; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SharpDX.DXGI.Resource screenResource;
                        OutputDuplicateFrameInformation duplicateFrameInformation;

                        // Try to get duplicated frame within given time
                        duplicatedOutput.AcquireNextFrame(10000, out duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource);

                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            // copy resource into memory that can be accessed by the CPU
                            using (var screenTexture2D = screenResource.QueryInterface<Texture2D>())
                                device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(screenTexture2D, screenTexture);

                            // Get the desktop capture texture
                            var mapSource = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(screenTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None);

                            // Create Drawing.Bitmap
                            var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                            var boundsRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

                            // Copy pixels from screen capture Texture to GDI bitmap
                            var mapDest = bitmap.LockBits(boundsRect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
                            var sourcePtr = mapSource.DataPointer;
                            var destPtr = mapDest.Scan0;
                            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                            {
                                // Copy a single line 
                                Utilities.CopyMemory(destPtr, sourcePtr, width * 4);

                                // Advance pointers
                                sourcePtr = IntPtr.Add(sourcePtr, mapSource.RowPitch);
                                destPtr = IntPtr.Add(destPtr, mapDest.Stride);
                            }

                            // Release source and dest locks
                            bitmap.UnlockBits(mapDest);
                            device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(screenTexture, 0);

                            // Save the output
                            bitmap.Save(destinationFolder + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + filename);

                            // Send Message
                            Main.Chat.AddMessage(null, "~b~Screenshot saved as " + filename);

                            // Capture done
                            captureDone = true;
                        }

                        screenResource.Dispose();
                        duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();

                    }
                    catch (SharpDXException e)
                    {
                        if (e.ResultCode.Code != SharpDX.DXGI.ResultCode.WaitTimeout.Result.Code)
                        {
                            throw e;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might be helpful to upload an image of what it should be looking like also.

Comment: @JustinStenning done :)

Comment: You mention in your title that you are using EasyHook although it doesn't seem to be the case / necessary in this example - my understanding is that the desktop duplication will work from another process is this correct? Have you tried something like Direct3DHook (on GitHub) does that give same result?

Comment: Direct3DHook works great, but not going to include it on my project tbh.

Comment: if you save as JPG or ignore the transparency channel does the image include the information you are expecting?